# Build solution with msbuild api

Tags: c#, msbuild, microsoft.build

I have been trying to build a solution using MSbuild API since few weeks now without success. I was able to build the solution by running a batch file inside my program that execute MSBUild.exe but I noticed that this is not a really good way of doing it. I googled a little and implemented the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Execution;
public static String BuildProject(String projectPath)
   {
        try
        {

            var props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            props["Configuration"] = "Debug";
            props["VisualStudioVersion"] = "12.0";
            var request = new BuildRequestData(projectPath, props, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
            var parms = new BuildParameters();

            var result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(parms, request);
            return result.OverallResult.ToString();
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }


    }
```

When I run my program a bin folder with a debug folder inside is created but the nothing happened. Using the batch file it takes around 2-5 mins to build the project. Is there anything that I am missing ?